# Classic ASP MSXML2.ServerHTTP Post - Youtube Api

Tags: asp-classic, header, youtube-api, serverxmlhttp

I am trying to build an application where i can upload files to youtube.
I have gotten OAuth working, and Youtube is returning a session!

The problem i am having is, youtube requires i make an XMLHTTP POST to get a url where i can upload through my web page.

I have no idea how to make an XMLHTTP Post with the extra parameters youtube requires.
They have code samples in PHP and .net both of which i dont understand yet :(

This is where i am stuck:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html#Sending_a_Browser_Upload_API_Request

I dont know how to Format an xml http command to have all those variables youtube wants.
Please help...

here is what they want..

```
 POST /action/GetUploadToken HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: AuthSub token="DXAA...sdb8"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc
Content-Length: 1941255
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.
    </media:description>
    <media:category
      scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People
    </media:category>
    <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>
```

Here is the code i have now:
I think i need the Headers?
When i post it i get a response of not authorized.
I also tried to create an old html  and try that but it does not work...

Have no idea how those paramenters are sent:

Here is what i got

```
Set  xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

URLString = "http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken"
SendString = ""
    SendString = SendString & "Authorization: AuthSub token=" &  token
xmlHttp.open "POST", URLString & "?" & SendString
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Host:", "gdata.youtube.com"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization: AuthSub token=", token
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "GData-Version:", "2"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length:", "<content_length>"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-"
xmlHttp.send SendString

If xmlHttp.Status >= 400 And xmlHttp.Status <= 599 Then
    Response.Write "<BR><BR><BR>Error Occured: " & xmlHttp.statusText
Else
  '  ReturnData = Replace(xmlHttp.responseText, "&", ",")
        Response.Write "<BR><BR><BR>WENT GOOD?<BR>" & xmlHttp.responseText
End If
```

Comment: Are you using VBScript or JScript?

Comment: Vbscript... thanks for looking into this...
I really gotta learn .NET or maybe PHP.  Im 10 years late =(

Comment: Do you need help adding the HTTP headers, or creating the XML? Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: I think i need help with the parameters,, they are blue in the code above... 

Updated with the asp code i have so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [setRequestHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536752(VS.85).aspx) doesn't take a colon.  It should just be

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "gdata.youtube.com"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "AuthSub token=" & token
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "GData-Version", "2"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "<content_length>" <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT!
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8"
```

Next, are you sending the correct content-length? This NEEDS to be accurate.
I assume the missing "8" from your Content-Type header at the end was a typo.

Finally, you NEED to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) right away and make your life simpler.

Comment: How do i measure the content length programatically?

Comment: THANKS
NO MORE ERRORS,, still gotta figure out some stuff, but its headers are fine... Thanks about fiddler too, got it

Comment: HOLY @#)*@$@#, look who answered my question!  this is why Stack Overflow rules... CFO finds time to answer posts!  SUPER COOL